# How to use decorators with JSDoc 3 and Babel.js?

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs, decorator, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I want to comment on a field with decorator like

```js
class Point {
  constructor(x, y) {
    // ...
  }

  /**
   * a variable with decorator
   */
  @test() val;

  getX() {
    // ...
  }

  getY() {
    // ...
  }

  static fromString(str) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

but I got an error

`Stage 2 decorators may only be used with a class or a class method (10:2)`

How to fix it? Is it possible to comment on decorators? How to config JSDoc Babel parser for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest JSDoc development version.

```
npm install git+https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc.git --save-dev
```